# What does EOI missing mean for mjpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

When encoding I sometimes see this ffmpeg warning

```
[mjpeg @ 0x5584bda90320] EOI missing, emulating
```

Already have googled but couldn't find anything useful. What does EOI stand for and what can cause this?

Here an example of the full command used:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -thread_queue_size 3072 -framerate 15.9 -i /var/www/videomail/production/source/var/production/tmp/clients/videomail.io/11e
7-bd8d-9a4e4a70-86c9-13af52a474c3/frames/%d.jpg -y -an -vcodec libx264 -filter:v drawtext=fontfile=/var/www/videomail/production/source/src/assets/fonts/Varela-Regular.ttf:text
=www.videomail.io:fontsize=12:fontcolor=0xFFFFFF@0.3:x=text_h:y=main_h-(text_h*2):shadowcolor=0x111111@0.15:shadowx=1:shadowy=1,scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2 -crf 23 -pix_f
mt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -profile:v baseline -level:v 3.1 -movflags +faststart -loglevel warning /var/www/videomail/production/source/var/production/tmp/clients/videomail.i
o/11e7-bd8d-9a4e4a70-86c9-13af52a474c3/videomail_preview.mp4
```

Here a report when it occurs: https://gist.github.com/binarykitchen/d8643bf0c0fb18f1b41cab7a322deb91

Comment: End Of Image (marker). Show full log. Are you updating input during conversion?

Comment: No, not altering input sources during conversion here. What else could be the cause?

Comment: Full log missing.

Comment: @Mulvya added example command - might help? as i dont have the full log due to the log level

Comment: Add -report to generate log. This is related to input parsing, not the command.

Comment: Ok, will add that report flag and see how it goes.

Comment: Hmmm, the -report option is polluting my root folder with many many log files. Bad on production. And it seems you cannot specify a different folder. Will have to remove that I am afraid.

Comment: I just wanted a single log pasted here for inspection.

Comment: finally, have a report here - hope you can tell me more: https://gist.github.com/binarykitchen/d8643bf0c0fb18f1b41cab7a322deb91

Comment: Does the output look ok despite the messages?

Comment: yes, output looks good regardless of those messages. feel free to check out the resulting video file yourself on www.videomail.io

Comment: Didn't get pinged so I missed your reply at first. I would just ignore the messages.

Answer (score 4):

Some of your input files are slightly corrupted. Most JPEG viewers don't even warn you if the End Of Image marker is missing.

Comment: I see. I am using this npm package to generate the jpg files https://github.com/binarykitchen/canvas-to-buffer ... should I amend some special bytes at the end of the buffer to avoid EOI marker warnings?

Comment: The question is whether the file contents is corrupted, or only the marker is missing. You can append `"\xFF\xD9"` to all jpeg files, and most likely this will silence the warning, but I cannot guarantee if the resulting video will look good.

Comment: true, here more specs on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format ... will try to patch canvas-to-buffer to see if this will make a difference

Comment: checked the canvas-to-buffer library and it does indeed have the EOI marker for jpeg files. see https://github.com/binarykitchen/canvas-to-buffer/blob/master/test/frame.test.js#L198. so must be something else.

Comment: From the gist it follows that the file /var/www/videomail/production/source/var/production/tmp/clients/videomail.io/11e
7-bd8d-9a4e4a70-86c9-13af52a474c3/frames/1.jpg is corrupted. There is probably no picture that can be recovered from it. But it's only one image, an the first one.